# How text from a resource with Environment.NewLine in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

in the resource file Messages_en.resx I have stored a text.
Name: TestView_01
Value: Hello. This is a test.

In Test.xaml this text is also displayed in a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockInformation" Text="{x:Static res:Messages_en.TestView_01}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

This works.

Now I want a line wrap in the text and I changed the value (no \r\n):
Hello.{0}This is a test.

In xaml the command Environment.NewLine can be called with:
x:Static sys:Environment.NewLine

sys is xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

What is the correct call of the text in the resource with the Environment.NewLine for the TextBlock?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than \r\n you can use hex - a special character or numeric character mapping.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xml-character-entities

```
 Hello.&#x0a;This is a test.
```

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello.&#x0a;This is a test." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```